# How to subclass an Ember class using ES6 syntax in Ember CLI

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'd like to create a custom Route class in Ember CLI. I have the following example working in an older app written with globals:

```
App.AuthenticatedRoute = Ember.Route.Extend({ 
  beforeModel: function() { 
    //Do some things
  }
});

App.DashboardRoute = App.AuthenticatedRoute.Extend({});
```

I'm familiar enough with ES6 modules to know that the example would look something like this...

```
var AuthenticatedRoute = Ember.Route.Extend({
  beforeModel: function() { 
    //
  }
});

export default AuthenticatedRoute;
```

...but I'm curious about the following:

1. Where would this live in the app structure?
2. How do I access this subclass in other modules?

**Update:**

To clarify my question: I was looking for information about where a custom implementation like this should live as opposed to a regular child route living in the app/routes dir. Ember CLI docs call out the following:

`To provide a custom implementation for generated routes (equivalent to App.Route when using globals), use app/routes/basic.js.`

http://www.ember-cli.com/#module-directory-naming-structure

...but I was not able to find any examples of this in practice, and it seems like an incomplete convention. I ended up treating the custom implementation as a standard route (app/routes/authenticated.js) and importing as needed.

Comment: Read the documentation.

Comment: @torazaburo wow, why didn't I think of that? thanks!

Comment: Yes, reading the docs is a trick I use a lot. Turns out it works better than staring into space, or throwing mud at the wall. Seriously, the Ember docs (including ember-cli) are quite comprehensive and the majority of basic stuff you need is there. For instance, it takes just a few seconds to find http://www.ember-cli.com/#naming-conventions.

Comment: @torazaburo first SO question here so my clarity could have been better, sure. I was looking for convention info, but called out syntax. Ember docs are excellent! Question updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use ember-cli, which is highly recommended, this would live in `app/routes/authenticated.js` and look like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
});
```

You can then import it in other modules as

`import authRoute from 'app/routes/authenticated'`

Comment: Thanks! This did the trick, although my import reference needed to be:

`import authRoute from './authenticated'`